# system () call... to open mybatchfiles.bat

Tags: c++, c, batch-file

I am getting the following error when using the `system()` call to run a batch file:

> 'C:\newfldr\mybatchfiles.bat' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

error at : system("C:\newfldr\mybatchfiles.bat");

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You very probably should write your string correctly, eg:

```
 system("C:\\newfldr\\mybatchfile.bat");
```

Remember that the C compiler is interpreting back slash escapes in constant string literals. In particular `\n` is a newline character, and `\\` encodes a backslash.

You could have printed your command string for debugging to find the issue (or use a debugger).

<sup>BTW, on Linux you don't have that issue because `\` is rarely used in file paths. Did you consider trying Linux? (it is fun).</sup>

Comment: You can also write it as `system("C:/newfldr/mybatchfile.bat");` so you wouldn't have to escape the backslashes.

Comment: no sir..!!! i write it as system("C:\\newfldr\\mybatchfiles.bat");
my main problem is, C:\newfldr\mybatchfiles.bat' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
can you plz tell me how to set for,
internal command
external command
operable program
or
batch file.
i have issue to set for batch file.

Comment: thanks, 
its working with : system("C:/newfldr/mybatchfile.bat");... thank you